# Spinner in primefaces, how to required press the button to forward or backward?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spinner

Sorry for my bad english.

Im using a spinner but i have a problem. I need that the the only way to change spinner value is press the button, not should change like a inputnumber.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You can try to add this to your spinner:  onkeydown="return false;"

Comment: Great! its working. Thanks